# ESLint says that semicolons are missing even after adding them

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have the following typescript interface on my project:

`

```
export default interface User {
    avatar: string;
    email: string;
    name: string;
}
```

`

After formatting with Prettier, ESLint keeps telling me that there are missing semicolons at the end of the code, now formatted like this:

`

```
export default interface User {
    avatar: string;
    cpf: string;
    email: string;
    name: string;
};;;;;;;;;;;
```

`

I could keep formatting and saving forever and it would still add semicolons at the end of that line

I have the following .eslintrc in my project

`

```
 module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'standard'
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly'
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
    '@typescript-eslint'
  ],
  rules: {
    "semi": [2, "always"]
  }
}
```

`

Answer (score 4):

I filed the issue at https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1695, and they responded that this is expected behavior, as you need to disable `semi`, and enable `@typescript-eslint/semi` instead.

Comment: This solved the issue for me, just disabled the default `semi` rule with the value `off` and enabled the `@typescript-eslint/semi` with the value `error`

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/123#issuecomment-503729012

Answer (score -1):

I always use semi rules as `never`. See documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'standard'
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly'
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
    '@typescript-eslint'
  ],
  rules: {
    "semi": [2, "never"]
  }
}
```

Not sure if one is better than the other, but in your case it should patch your problem.
I'm surprised it is on `always`; did you set it yourself?